# Running as a host user within a Docker container

Tags: sudo, development, docker, useradd, flask

In my team we use Docker containers to locally run our website applications while we do development on them.

Assuming I'm working on a Flask app at `app.py` with dependencies in `requirements.txt`, a working flow would look roughly like this:

```
# I am "robin" and I am in the docker group
$ whoami
robin
$ groups
robin docker

# Install dependencies into a docker volume
$ docker run -ti -v `pwd`:`pwd` -w `pwd` -v pydeps:/usr/local python:3-slim pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting Flask==0.12.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
# ... etc.

# Run the app using the same docker volume
$ docker run -ti -v `pwd`:`pwd` -w `pwd` -v pydeps:/usr/local -e FLASK_APP=app.py -e FLASK_DEBUG=true -p 5000:5000 python:3-slim flask run -h 0.0.0.0
 * Serving Flask app "app"
 * Forcing debug mode on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 251-131-649
```

Now we have a local server running our application, and we can make changes to the local files and the server will refresh as needed.

In the above example, the application end up running as the `root` user. This isn't a problem unless the application writes files back into the working directory. If it does then we could end up with files (e.g. something like `cache.sqlite` or `debug.log`) in our working directory owned by `root`. This has caused a number of problems for users in our team.

For our other applications we've solved this by running the application with the *host user's* UID and GID - e.g. for a Django app:

```
$ docker run -ti -u `id -u`:`id -g` -v `pwd`:`pwd` -w `pwd` -v pydeps:/usr/local -p 8000:8000 python:3-slim ./manage.py runserver
```

In this case, the application will be running as a *non-existent* user with ID `1000` inside the container, but any files written to the host directory end up correctly owned by the `robin` user. This works fine in Django.

However, Flask refuses to run as a non-existent user (in debug mode):

```
$ docker run -ti -u `id -u`:`id -g` -v `pwd`:`pwd` -w `pwd` -v pydeps:/usr/local -e FLASK_APP=app.py -e FLASK_DEBUG=true -p 5000:5000 python:3-slim flask run -h 0.0.0.0
 * Serving Flask app "app"
 * Forcing debug mode on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/getpass.py", line 169, in getuser
    return pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0]
KeyError: 'getpwuid(): uid not found: 1000'
```

Does anyone know if there's any way that I could either:

- Make Flask not worry about the unassigned user-id, or
- Somehow dynamically assign the user ID to a username at runtime, or
- Otherwise allow the docker application to create files on the host as the host user?

The only solution I can think of right now (super hacky) is to change the permissions of `/etc/passwd` in the docker image to be globally writeable, and then add a new line to that file at runtime to assign the new UID/GID pair to a username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was [posted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45836272/running-as-a-host-user-within-a-docker-container/45959754#45959754) by [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1094246/robert):

---

You can share the host's passwd file:

```
docker run -ti -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd -u `id -u`:`id -g` -v `pwd`:`pwd` -w `pwd` -v pydeps:/usr/local -p 8000:8000 python:3-slim ./manage.py runserver
```

Or, add the user to the image with `useradd`, using `/etc` as volume, in the same way you use `/usr/local`:

```
docker run -v etcvol:/etc python..... useradd -u `id -u` $USER
```

(Both `id -u` and $USER are resolved in the host shell, before docker receive the command)